# Android Preference android:icon getIcon null

Tags: android, icons, preference

I am trying to call `getIcon` on a `Preference` declared in xml for android. I am calling it in the `onCreate` for the preference `Activity` after all the resources have been inflated.

The icon shows up but if I do `findPreference(key)` then it calls `getIcon` and on that preference the icon returned is `null`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Preference doesn't resolve icons set from XML until it's bound for the first time. You could extend `Preference`, manually load the icon from the `AttributeSet` supplied to the constructor, and pass that to `setIcon(int)`. Or you could postpone the `getIcon()` call until the preference has been displayed on screen.